# How to fix file path error ? index.php? It wasnt working from the get go so am not sure what to do

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was following a demo tutorial but I encountered this error and I fooled everything to the letter so am not sure what to do ...

> Warning: include(home.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingcart\index.php on line 9

> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'home.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingcart\index.php on line 9

This is the index.php file code -

```
<?php
session_start();
// Include functions and connect to the database using PDO MySQL
include 'functions.php';
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();
// Page is set to home (home.php) by default, so when the visitor visits that will be the page they see.
$page = isset($_GET['page']) && file_exists($_GET['page'] . '.php') ? $_GET['page'] : 'home';
// Include and show the requested page
include $page . '.php';
?>
```

Comment: `home.php` file is there in folder path?

Comment: Without knowing your apps file structure (where all the files are in relation to each other), it's impossible for us to know what you need to do to fix the issue.

Comment: \-- shoppingcart
|-- functions.php
|-- index.php
|-- home.php
|-- products.php
|-- product.php
|-- cart.php
|-- placeorder.php
|-- style.css
\-- imgs
|-- featured-image.jpg
|-- camera.jpg
|-- headphones.jpg
|-- wallet.jpg
|-- watch.jpg

Comment: That's what the file structure looks like, for now, I found the location to the of the pear file and just place the file in files in there but its not the best of solutions  it still not showing the home. page content correctly

Answer (score 2):

First thing to check is that `home.php` is in the same folder as `index.php` (so they're next to each other).

Remember that the path `"home.php"` references a sibling page in the same folder so if the file isn't there, you'll get this error.

On the other hand, if `home.php` is not meant to be a sibling of `index.php` and so, is located somewhere else in your directory structure, you'll need to update the value that references it's path

Comment: i understand but , as it stands the home.php file is sibling as you say they are in the same location as well  the index.php is basically a routing file that interconnects the pages starting the session for each link I belive

Comment: Since they're siblings and located correctly in relation to one another, the next thing to assess would be whether or not the path value is actually correct. Things to look for: What's the value of `$_GET['page']`, what's the value of `$page` after it has been assigned and what would be the value of `$page . '.php'` that you're outputting as the target on the include? If the page is there, then the problem is most likely how you're identifying it in the code